# Controller class App\Controllers\Personalbudget not found

Tags: php

When I click link to: my-site/personalbudget/addexpense
error appears:

> Uncaught exception: 'Exception'

> Message: 'Controller class App\Controllers\Personalbudget not found'

> Stack trace:

> 0 /home/klient.dhosting.pl/ppp/my-web-site/public_html/index.php(42): Core\Router->dispatch('personalbudget/...')
> #1 {main}
> Thrown in '/home/klient.dhosting.pl/ppp/my-web-site/Core/Router.php' on line 80`

Below I present router.php and the personalBudget.php header:

router.php

```
<?php

namespace Core;

class Router
{

public function dispatch($url)
    {
        $url = $this->removeQueryStringVariables($url);

        if ($this->match($url)) {
            $controller = $this->params['controller'];
            $controller = $this->convertToStudlyCaps($controller);
            $controller = $this->getNamespace() . $controller;

            if (class_exists($controller)) {
                $controller_object = new $controller($this->params);

                $action = $this->params['action'];
                $action = $this->convertToCamelCase($action);

                if (is_callable([$controller_object, $action])) {
                    $controller_object->$action();

                } else {
                    throw new \Exception("Method $action (in controller $controller) not found");
                }
            } else {
                throw new \Exception("Controller class $controller not found");
            }
        } else {
            throw new \Exception('No route matched.', 404);
        }
    }
}
```

personalBudget.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use \Core\View;
use \App\Models\ModelPersonalBudget;
use \App\Models\User;



use \App\Auth;
use \App\Flash;

#[\AllowDynamicProperties]
class personalBudget extends \Core\Controller
```

I would like to add that it happens only on server because everything works fine on localhost.

How can I solve this problem because everything works fine on localhost but if my-web-site is on server an error occured.

Comment: Does your localhost has the same PHP version as your server?

Comment: No, these versions aren't the same. On my localhost is 8.2.0, on my server is  8.1.22.
Do I have to change it? If so, how?

Comment: What’s the content of the $controller variable? You can try to keep a log of it to see what value it resolves to.

Comment: I renamed class "personalBudget" to "Personalbudget" and also renamed "PersonalBudget.php" to "Personalbudget.php".
These actions solved my problems.